# Include different files per build configuration

Tags: visual-studio-2010, build

We have two different build configurations: Debug and Production.

Part of the build includes a cert used to access a third party site. In debug, we use a staging cert and in production we use the live production cert.

How can I ensure when the solution is built in the debug configuration that the staging cert is included and when its built in production, the production cert is included?

**EDIT**

Here's my solution from Scotty's suggestion (this was put into the Post-Build event command-line section):

```
IF $(ConfigurationName) == Release copy $(ProjectDir)resources\prod.p12 $(TargetDir)resources

IF $(ConfigurationName) == Debug copy $(ProjectDir)resources\staging.p12 $(TargetDir)resources
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depends how your 'cert' is included in your project.

If it's a C/C++ file, right-click the file in Solution Explorer, open Properties > General > **Excluded from Build**. Exclude one file for your Debug build and one for your Release build.

If it's an external file or command, you can use **Build Events** for each configuration. Open your project Properties > Configuration Properties > Build Events > Post-Build Event (or another event if you like). From there you can run whatever command line you want.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the build events. It proved to be the solution I needed.

Answer (score -1):

I think you could use DEBUG directive for loading certificates:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

 public class CertLoader
{
#if DEBUG
 public bool LoadStartingCert()
{
//...load it
}
//in other case load prod cert
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the thought! However this approach seems to rely on sending both the staging and prod certs to production which is something I try to not to do. But was still a good reminder of the directives.