# How to conditionally include MASM .asm files depending on platform/configuration (32/64-bit)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, masm

I'm using Visual Studio 2010.  I have two different MASM assembly files, one for 32-bit builds and one for 64-bit.  The relevant part of my `.vcxproj` looks like this:

```xml
  <ItemGroup>
    <MASM Include="asmcode32.asm" Condition="'$(Platform)'=='Win32'" />
    <MASM Include="asmcode64.asm" Condition="'$(Platform)'=='x64'" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

My problem is this: The only file shown in Solution Explorer is the one for whichever configuration (`Win32` / `x64`) is selected *when Visual Studio is opened*. Even unloading and reloading the project is insufficient - I must close and re-open visual studio for the other file to be shown.

I would prefer that both files be shown all the time, regardless of which configuration is selected.  I could live with the visible item changing, depending on which solution is selected.

---

**Example:**

Visual Studio is opened with the `x64` configuration selected. Only `asmcode64.asm` is shown:

[image: asmcode64.asm is shown]

When I change to the `Win32` configuration (via the "Solution Platforms" drop-down), `asmcode32.asm` is still not visible. Again, even unload + reload does not make it visible.

With `Win32` still selected, I can close Visual Studio and re-open it. Only *now* is `asmcode32.asm` visible:

[image]

---

Is there something else I can do with my `.vcxproj` file to show both files?

Perhaps adding the `Condition=` to the `<MASM` items was not the correct solution. If this is indeed the case, how can I configure the project to compile as I intend it?

This only applies to MASM .asm files. The equivalent operation for C/C++ files is to [use the "Excluded From Build" option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11615603/include-different-files-per-build-configuration) in the file's properties (this option doesn't exist for MASM files):

[image: "Excluded From Build" option in C file property pages]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You're<sup>1</sup> doing it wrong.**

The `Conditional=` solution works, but using it causes the behavior you're<sup>1</sup> seeing.  Visual Studio appears to only evaluate which files will be shown in the Solution Explorer once. Basically this makes Visual Studio think that the file isn't even a part of the project.

The *real* solution is to use the same `<ExcludedFromBuild>` tags that the C files use (which are added when you select the "Excluded From Build" option in the file's properties pages.

```xml
  <ItemGroup>
    <!-- This causes the items to not be shown in Solution Explorer -->
    <!--
    <MASM Include="asmcode32.asm" Condition="'$(Platform)'=='Win32'" />
    <MASM Include="asmcode64.asm" Condition="'$(Platform)'=='x64'" />
    -->

    <!-- This is the right solution. -->
    <MASM Include="asmcode32.asm">
      <ExcludedFromBuild Condition="'$(Platform)'=='x64'">true</ExcludedFromBuild>
    </MASM>
    <MASM Include="asmcode64.asm">
      <ExcludedFromBuild Condition="'$(Platform)'=='Win32'">true</ExcludedFromBuild>
    </MASM>
  </ItemGroup>
```

It's a shame that this option is not exposed via the GUI, like it is for C files.

<sup>1 - "I'm"</sup>